# Increasing value in text file

Tags: bash, awk

I've got the following text file:

```
dsfgsdgf dsfsdg
Version: 29.15-005
dfs sdfg sdf g
dsfsdfgsdfgsfdg
```

So it contains a bunch of data and there is a unique line with

```
Version:
```

The first time the script is called, 29.15-005 will replaced by 29.15-006. The next time 29.15-006 will be replaced 29.15-007 etc etc

I dont need to check what happens when it gets to -999 as the value will never get that high.

Seen various awk scripts using F and OFS but can't seem to work out how to apply to the above.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

The text file will be different each time its called with other data in it (and different lengths) , but the info from the Version: will remain constant.

Comment: I'm confused about your requirements. It sounds like you have a file with `5` in it and you want a script that when called on that file will output a copy of the file but with the `5` changed to a `6`. Then the next time you call that same script on that same file it will change the `5` to a `7`. wrt `The text file will be different each time its called with other data in it` - that means the file with the `5` will change independently between (during?) invocations of the tool so the `5` will remain a `5` but the rest of the file's contents will change. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Maybe a little but... are you saying you want the script to change the input file? You say `The text file will be different each time its called` - is that relevant to the problem you're asking for help with? If the answer is "it's not" then please get rid of that statement as it's just obfuscating the question. If the answer is "it is" then please edit your question to state in what way because right now I can't imagine why we'd care if the contents change from one set of data we don't see in your example to some other set of data we don't see in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want might be (using GNU awk for inplace editing):

```
$ cat file
dsfgsdgf dsfsdg
Version: 29.15-005
dfs sdfg sdf g
dsfsdfgsdfgsfdg

$ awk -i inplace 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"} /Version:/{$2=sprintf("%03d",($2+1))} 1' file

$ cat file
dsfgsdgf dsfsdg
Version: 29.15-006
dfs sdfg sdf g
dsfsdfgsdfgsfdg
```

With other awks do `awk 'script' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: Works great. A nice one liner which does the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 awk -F- -v OFS=- '
       /^Version:/{
           incr=sprintf("%03d", ($2 + 1))
           $2=incr
       }1' file > tmpFile && /bin/mv tmpFile file
```

**output**

```
dsfgsdgf dsfsdg
Version: 29.15-006
dfs sdfg sdf g
dsfsdfgsdfgsfdg
```

The `/^Version:/` ensures that the script only processes the line of interest.

The `1` after the closing `}` char ensures that all lines of the file are printed.

IHTH